# Why can't you delete a Python variable in VSCode Debug Console?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I encountered this strange behavior in VS Code debugger when stepping line by line through the code.

Before `print(var1)`, when I execute `del var1` in the Debug Console, it will delete `var1`, and the next line `print(var1)` will fail as expected.

However, in `main()`, when I execute `del var2` in the Debug Console, it doesn't do anything. The next line `print(var2)` executes successfully. `var2 = 'new'` will change the value in Debug Console, but `del var2` doesn't delete the variable.

Is there any reason for this inconsistent behavior? It seems VS Code Debug Consol won't delete variables inside a function. When I do the same debugging with `pdb`, it works as expected (`var2` gets deleted).

```py
var1 = 'value1'
# del var1 (in vscode Debug Console)
print(var1)

def main():
    var2 = 'value2'
    # del var2 (in vscode Debug Console)
    print(var2)

main()
```

VS Code v1.61.1 (Sep 2021)
Python v3.9.5